# Trigger After Update In SQL Compiles But Does Not Seem To Fire

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, triggers

I have a trigger that should update a certain column, `Points`, after an update is made to a record in that same row. To do this, I have created a series of functions `calc_extrapoint` and `calc_fieldgoalpoint` to facilitate the process. Both of these functions work and return the correct values when run manually.

However, when I try to have the trigger fire after an update to the table, which most likely will happen with the columns `ExtraPoint` or `FieldGoal` the `Points` column is not updated as I'd expect.

For example iniitally in my table all values of each record starts as 0, 0, 0 for points, extra point, and field goal columns respectively. When I update the extra point column though to say 2, I expect the Points column to be 2. If I update again this time with field goal points to 2, I expect my Points column to be set to 8.

```
create or replace function calc_points() returns trigger as $$
    begin
        NEW."Points" :=  calc_extrapoint(NEW."ExtraPoint") + calc_fieldgoalpoint(NEW."FieldGoal");
    return NEW;
    end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP TRIGGER calc_points on playerdata;
CREATE TRIGGER calc_points AFTER UPDATE ON playerdata
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE calc_points();
```

The trigger and functions all compile appropriately, but are not firing as expected. Is there something I'm missing to complete the action?

Answer (score 2):

Modifying `NEW` in an `AFTER` trigger won't do anything. The row has already been written. Put a `RAISE NOTICE 'Trigger fired';` in there; you'll get the notice. It's just that the trigger fires, but does nothing.

That's why we have `BEFORE` triggers. If you want to modify the row to be written to the table, you must use a `BEFORE` trigger.

Comment: My concern is I do not know which column is going to be updated every time. I can't use a before trigger because then if I try to access the  column that is not updated via `NEW` I will get no value back because there is no new value (correct me if I'm wrong). Perhaps I'm missing something... Do you think you might post a link to an example like the one you're describing with the `raise notice`, after some quick googling I'm not finding anything that seems to lead me down the correct path

Comment: If you only want to fire a trigger when a particular column changes, use a `WHEN` clause on the trigger, or compare `OLD` and `NEW` values. This is all in the documentation...

Comment: I follow you now. Truth be told though, I have 12 columns of statistics that I'm tracking. If I were to use if statements to compare old and new value comparisons to know which values to take to calculate the `points` column, I'd have 12 if statements. On top of that its possible multiple columns might be updated at a time, so even more if statements would be needed. Hence, my inclination to use `after update`. Is there a simple way to access that row that was updated, grab the values from each column, compute the points and place that back into the `points` column using `after`?

Comment: You can issue a new `UPDATE` from the `AFTER` trigger, but it will cause infinite recursion when the `UPDATE` triggers a new copy of the `AFTER` trigger to fire. Use a `BEFORE` trigger, that's what they're for. You can have a single trigger check many columns.